# How does one have rowspan in UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, html-table

How do I build the following view?

I want to build a form using a standard `UITableViewController`, but I need to have an image that spans the first two rows.  Rows have text in them (not pictured).

One way I've considered is to have the Image and first two rows actually be one row with another `UITableView` embedded inside it, with scrolling disabled.

But I'd really like to do something with indenting.

```
                                UITableView
                          +-----+---------------+
                          |     |               |  <---+ Row 0
        UIImageView +---> |     +---------------+
                          |     |               |  <---+ Row 1
                          +-----+---------------+
                          |                     |  <---+ Row 2
                          +---------------------+
                          |                     |
                          +---------------------+
                          |                     |
                          +---------------------+
                          |                     |
                          +----------------
                          |
                          +-----------
                          |
                          +------
                          |            Etc..
                          +--
                          |
```

How can I accomplish this, using the fewest widgets / least amount of code (for iOS 4+)?

Comment: Does providing a tall image as the imageview for the first cell and no image for the second cell provide a credible solution? I imagine it might not if it the cell view clips it's subviews.

Comment: No, I don't think so.  I guess I could try cutting the image and half and making it line up... but I want to have a grouped table where row 0 and 1 are the same group and row 2 through n are a different group, and the image should live outside the row background (i.e. it should be outside the rounded corners).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up putting a `UIImageView` and a nested `UITableView` inside the row 0 `UITableViewCell`.  The nested `UITableView` has scrolling disabled and provides one group with two rows.  Then I just had to fudge the frame a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You've probably realized this isn't standard, so I think your three options are:

1. Two images that fit to look like one.
2. rows 1 & 2 are actually 1 row that looks like it's two rows.
3. row 1 has an image as big as the first two rows, and subview clipping is off so it overlays row two.

I'd be inclined to use option #1, but if the images will change or be dynamic, I might go for option #2

Comment: What about adding an image view as a subview of the UITableView?

Comment: Rog: I think from the question he wanted the imagery to scroll naturally with the uitableviewcell

Comment: Yes, it should scroll with row 0 and row 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to subclass UITableViewCell for your first 2 cells. You should be able to lay it out to look like 1 big cell or your rowspanned cells, then just use the default for all the remaining cells.